# Epoch time for last calender Month

Tags: python, bash, timestamp, epoch

Problem:

I want to generate epoch start and end time for last calender Month.

Suppose today in GMT is `GMT: Wednesday, June 13, 2018 7:38:21 AM`
I need to generate start epoch and end epoch time for GMT for last month in calender which is not 30 days before today.

It means today epoch `1528875278 - 2592000` is not correct.

What i requres is something like this.

start: 1527964200,endtime:1528568999
Which actually translates to

```
start : Saturday, May 1, 2018 6:30:00 PM
end   : Saturday, May 31, 2018 6:29:59 PM
```

What i tried:

```
import time
today_time = int(time.time())
start_time = int(time.time()) - 2592000 +/- some_bias
end_time   = int(time.time()) - 2592000 +/- some_bias
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `datetime` module in python *(for both 2.X and 3.X)*. Here is an example:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
end_of_last_month = today.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start_of_last_month = end_of_last_month.replace(day=1)
```

To convert to epoch time, you can do the following in python 3.3+

```
start_epoch = int(start_of_last_month.timestamp())
end_epoch = int(end_of_last_month.timestamp())
```

In earlier versions of python, it can be done as:

```
start_epoch = int(start_of_last_month.strftime('%s'))
end_epoch = int(end_of_last_month.strftime('%s'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get 1st day of previous month:

```
TZ=GMT date -d "$(date +"%Y-%m-01") -1 month"
```

And use this to get last date of previous month:

```
date -d "$(date +"%Y-%m-01") -1 day"
```

For using `epoch` time and variables:

```
startTime=$(TZ=GMT date -d "$(date +"%Y-%m-01") -1 month" '%s')
endTime=$(date -d "$(date +"%Y-%m-01") -1 day" '%s')
```